# Two accounts on same computer - how can I make a share folder for both?

Tags: directory, users, shared-folders

I need a shared folder. My wife and I need to exchange files on the same computer. How can we do that?

Comment: Never tried but may be the Public folder in the User's home folder would share the stuff system-wide.

Comment: Please subscribe to blueprint on launchpad https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/local-file-share/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a tutorial from Ubuntu Forums: [How to create a shared folder for multiple local users](http://art.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8983087&postcount=25).

> 1. Install bindfs.
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install bindfs
>    ```
> 2. Create a hidden and a visible directory for the files.
>
>    ```
>    sudo mkdir /home/.media # create a hidden directory 
>    sudo mkdir /home/media
>    ```
> 3. Create a new group.
>
>    ```
>    sudo groupadd media
>    ```
> 4. Add the user(s) to the group.
>
>    ```
>    sudo gpasswd -a usrname media
>    ```
>
>    Repeat this for all users. Log out and log back in your current user.
> 5. Edit the fstab file.
>
>    ```
>    sudoedit /etc/fstab
>    ```
> 6. Add a new entry at the end of the file.
>
>    ```
>    bindfs#/home/.media    /home/media    fuse    group=media,perms=g=rwx
>    ```
> 7. Mount the filesystems mentioned in fstab.
>
>    ```
>    sudo mount -a
>    ```
> 8. Move the files you want to share in the `/home/media` directory.

Comment: **bindfs** is nice but not suitable for less experienced users as it involves quite a lot of changes to the standard system configuration (e.g. editing of fstab, adding user groups etc.).

Comment: Maybe you should add an excerpt of the page to this answer.

Comment: I tried this tutorial. But I can't create any files in media folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constant internet connection and bandwidth is not a problem, then you could use Ubuntu One.

Answer (score 0):

bindfs is documented in the Ubuntu wiki:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Bindfs-SharedDirectoryLocalUsers