# How do I share documents with multiple users on the same PC?

Tags: files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two accounts on same computer how to make a share folder for both?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14791/two-accounts-on-same-computer-how-to-make-a-share-folder-for-both)
>   [Shared folders for all users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52584/shared-folders-for-all-users)

I am not entirely new to Linux, but I am now having my daughters and son explore Linux and I was wondering where would I put documents and files that are shared between all of the users?

Comment: The best answer in the duplicate listed is a link only answer.  We need some proper answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done this in the past (shared laptop between my wife and myself) was to create a user/new group and home directory, make myself and my wife members of the new group and set permissions so that properties of files are inherited regardless of who creates theem.