# Moving the Pictures, Documents, Music into alternative directory

Tags: 18.04, directory, home-directory

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 along with windows 10. The installation was done into an SSD which contained the Windows OS, but of course, partitioned. So, the Windows OS is in one partition and the Linux in other.

I created a directory `common` and the path of the directory is

`\home\user\common`

and I tried to move Pictures, Documents, Desktop etc., to this directory. I also created the symbolic links in the file `user-dirs. dirs` but no luck. Here is an example of how it was and how I changed it -

`XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"`

I created a directory `common` in `home/user` and changed the file as follows,

`XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/common/Desktop"`

Since this doesn't work I want to know if there is an alternative solution or should I reinstall the OS?

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. What is the purpose of `/home/user/common`? Do you have multiple users and do you want to share these folders with them? Or do you want all the users to have a common set of Pictures, Documents, and Music folder? The later may create problems as one user may not have the correct rights to modify or delete the files created by another user. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1329473/edit) and and explain it better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I share documents with multiple users on the same PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231490/how-do-i-share-documents-with-multiple-users-on-the-same-pc)

Comment: I create another data partition, either another drive or if room on same drive. And then mount data partition and link folders back into /home. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Also, the reference to Windows confuses me a bit. How is this relevant to your problem?

Comment: I have updated the question. Is it more clear now? All I want to do is move the existing Pictures, Videos directory from their default location to another and change the symbolic links @user68186

Comment: @user68186 Its alright I found the solution. I was changing the user-dirs.dirs file in the root directory. But then I found out there is one more file with the same file name and  characteristics in home directory. I just changed symbolic links in that and everything looks good now. Thanks for your suggestions.