# Sharing files to another account

Tags: users, file-sharing

I have just opened an account on the system settings on my PC for family members. I want to put some pictures and videos from my account on to theirs.

How can I do that?

Comment: share on the same PC or across PC? Share meaning ro of full access ? `sudo mkdir /media/pictures ; sudo chown your_user:users /media/pictures; chmod 775 /media/pictures`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two accounts on same computer how to make a share folder for both?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14791/two-accounts-on-same-computer-how-to-make-a-share-folder-for-both)

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple. Here it's not really sharing; because users are on the same PC, you are just copying or moving files between directories.

You can navigate to user account `cd /home/user/` , then you can move your files into their Documents folder for example:

```
cp /home/your-user/testfile /home/their-user/Documents/
```

Comment: It is simple, but by default you will need `sudo` for this as `your-user`, though not as `their-user`, because your user won't have write permission in their home directory

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  The easiest way would be to make a folder in `/home`, let's call it `share` and give it permissions for all users to read and write to the folder with `chmod 776`.  This isn't the most secure way to go about doing it, as it allows anyone with access to the system to put files into the folder.  The folder permissions would look like this (if you used `ls -l`):

```
drwxrwxrw- user user 4096 share
```

a more secure way to allow sharing between accounts would be through the use of groups **and** folder permissions.  Here are the steps:

**1)** Add a group called `familyshare`:

```
sudo groupadd family share
```

**2)** Add the user you created for your family (let's call it `family`, but it can be whatever you want) to the group:

```
sudo useradd -G familyshare family
```

**3)** Create the directory that you want to share with your family in `/home` (let's call this directory `share`)

```
cd /home
sudo mkdir share
chown :familyshare share
chmod 774 share
```

**4)** Check the permissions on the directory and test it with the `family` user:

```
ls -l /home
#you should see something that looks like this
drwxrwxr-- user familyshare 4096 share
su family
cd /home/share
mkdir test
```

If everything went according to plan, there should be a folder called `test` inside the `share` directory.  Anyone who is a member of the group `familyshare` should be able to read, write, and execute files in the `share` directory.  If you do not want them to be able to execute files, but still read and write, you can change the permissions to using `chmod 764` on the `share` directory.

Comment: a 6 or 4 permission on a directory is useless - may as well be 0, because directories need execute permission to be accessed. Files don't get execute permission just because their parent directories have it (and no umask setting will allow creation of executable files) - x bits always have to be added. Also, pictures and videos don't need execute permission. So, the information you've given about permissions in this answer is misleading